# Rails/JS - Update video source src after a delay

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

When someone uploads a video in my app, it gets processed in AWS Lambda which takes about 90 seconds.

I want to be able to show this updated video without having to reload the Show.html.erb page

The path for the video is accessed via the instance `@aws_url`

The **Show method** in my controller:

```
def show
    @gif = Gif.friendly.find(params[:id])
    gon.gif = @gif
    ...
    if Rails.env.production?
       @aws_url = @gif.video.attachment.service_url.sub(/\?.*/, '')
       @aws_url = @aws_url.insert(21, '-resized')
       @aws_url = @aws_url + '.mp4'
    end 
end
```

The relevant section in **show.html.erb** page:

```
<div id="video">
   <video width="300" controls autoplay loop mute>
      <source src=<%= @aws_url %> type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
</div>
```

And the JS. Here I am showing a progress bar for a set amount of time, after which I want to hide the progress bar and show the video. I've attempted to pass the @aws_url to the "#video" element but this just results in `<%= escape_javascript(render @aws_url) %>` being shown.

```
$(function(){
    if($("#gif_show").length > 0) {

            document.getElementById('video').style.visibility = "hidden";
            var bar1 = new ldBar("#myItem1");
            var bar2 = document.getElementById('myItem1').ldBar;
            bar2.set(100);

            var milliSecTime = gon.target_time * 1000;
            setTimeout(function() { 
                $('myItem1').innerHTML = "";
                $("#video").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @aws_url) %>");
                $('video').style.visibility = "visible";

            }, milliSecTime);
    }
});
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: I found a solution which I've added to my original post

Comment: Please don't do that. Instead you can add an answer to the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

My mistake was to confuse which html element to pass the url and how to configure those elements. The video source can be created in the JS file and then appended to the existing video element.

Additionally the video id should be like this:

```
<video width="300" controls autoplay loop mute id="video">        
</video>
```

JS file:

```
$(function(){
    if($("#gif_show").length > 0) {

            document.getElementById('video').style.visibility = "hidden";
            var bar1 = new ldBar("#myItem1");
            var bar2 = document.getElementById('myItem1').ldBar;
            bar2.set(100);

            var milliSecTime = gon.target_time * 1000;

            function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {
                var source = document.createElement('source');

                source.src = src;
                source.type = type;

                element.appendChild(source);
            };

            setTimeout(function() { 

                var video = document.getElementById('video');

                addSourceToVideo(video, gon.aws_url, 'video/mp4')

                document.getElementById("myItem1").innerHTML = "";

                document.getElementById('video').style.visibility = "visible";
                video.play();
            }, milliSecTime);
    }
});
```